# Discord bot repeating the command but not an event in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to ask something.I got stuck on something.I wanted to add some new features to my bot such as swear words so that making cleaner server.I finished my code and tried to give command which is **!dc greetings**(!dc is my command_prefix btw).My bot sent **'Hi everyone'** message for 7 times.That 7 times is same number as the number of swear words in **"Badwords.txt"**.By looking these,that repeating issue is related to this file handling codes(or not idk).Interesting thins is when I write swear word into server's chatbox,bot send only one *"Please do not use this word ever"* message.So How can i prevent bot not to repeat for many times?Thank you

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True,presences=True)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)

#Below command gets repeated 7 times everytime.That number is same as the number of swear words in "Badwords.txt"
@client.command(aliases=["sayHi"]) 
async def greetings(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi everyone')

#My purpose in the below codes is countering profanity

with open("Badwords.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    word = f.read()
    badwords = word.split(",")  

#In the below event,bot sends message only 1 time for 1 message 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    for x in badwords:
        if x in msg:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Please do not use this word ever")
        else:
            await client.process_commands(message) 
client.run(Token)
```

Comment: You're processing commands on each loop when the else part is reached. You should do it *outside* the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the `await client.process_commands(message)` out of the `else` statement. I have also moved the `with open` inside the on message event so everything a message is sent, it will open the file to check if the message contained a bad word.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True,presences=True)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)

@client.command(aliases=["sayHi"]) 
async def greetings(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi everyone')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    with open("Badwords.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        word = f.read()
        badwords = word.split(",") 
    for x in badwords:
        if x in msg:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send("Please do not use this word ever")
        else:
            return
    await client.process_commands(message)
client.run(Token)
```

`await client.process_commands(message)` was taken out of the `else` statement because, with your current code, the bot would only process the commands if the message did NOT contain a bad word. But we need it to process the commands every time a message is sent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I appreciate your help.

Comment: @hARASİVa I'm glad it worked for you! If it did help you, please mark this answer as correct.